# C++ program output uses space on my disk?

Tags: c++, project, output, diskspace

I'm creating a C++ project where the programs used produce a lot of output message (all of them are printed by cout), but I can decide to silent something like the 95% of them.

However, when I decide to print them all, I can see the space on my disk decreasing very fast (something like 1 MB every 2 seconds!).

So, those programs must be run for hours, so you can imagine the amount of space occupied on my disk!

However, if I restart my pc, the space on my disk will be restored.

Another note: if I decide to silent the programs (and left only 5% of message), the space on disk occupied is much less!

So I think that this problem is correlated to the output messages, but how I can avoid it without silent them all?

I'm using ubuntu

Thank to all that will answer to my question!

Comment: Maybe you are using a redirect in the tmp folder or (clog) ?

Comment: @Alexis tmp will probably be filled up in not time.

Comment: What library/api is used to "produce a lot of output message"? What OS is this program running on? There is nothing _inherent C++_ that would cause output to standard output to take up disk space, so it's either the program itself or something in the way the program is run (like redirecting output to a tmp file).

Comment: @dhavenith I edited the initial message adding the OS used (ubuntu) and the command used for the output (classic cout). However, I create tmp file, but all of them are deleted (through the remove instruction) .

Comment: Those messages, are they sent to stdout or to stderr? Also, you say "programs", so it's multiple programs that are working together? Are they piping output to each other?